# What is the more accurate word for "lazy" in Bill Gates' quote

Tags: word-choice

Bill Gates said that

> “I choose a lazy person to do a hard job. Because a lazy person will find an easy way to do it.”

I have a lazy brother who is

- lazy to take a bath and brush his teeth
- lazy to clean his room, let alone our house
- lazy to study
- lazy to help others

I also have a friend who is

- lazy to help others voluntarily
- lazy to work hard with a low salary
- lazy to go to church because he does not want to meet his ex girlfriend

## Question

It seems to me, the word "lazy" in Bill Gates' quote is similar to ones I used for my friend. In order to exclude the meaning of "lazy" that I used for my brother, what is the more specific, accurate word instead of "lazy" for Bill Gates' quote?

Comment: I believe Bill Gates will not choose my brother!

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - pretty much agree, although doesn't being called 'lazy' suggest a (mild) criticism.  Is any one happy to be thought of as lazy?  I wouldn't say Bill Gates' usage implied he thinks being lazy is a good thing.

Comment: In a computer setting, one can talk about e.g. 'lazy evaluation', when considering strategies which utilize the machine's resources no more than strictly necessary. Lazy evaluation in a program is an evaluation strategy which delays the evaluation of an expression until its value is needed and which also avoids repeated evaluations. Laziness in approaching any task may have connotations of efficiency and thoughtful discarding of unnecessary or wasteful methods.

Comment: Have you looked up the word *lazy* in a dictionary for its meaning and usage?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - I like this use of lazy.  Do you suppose this is what Bill Gates was meaning?

Comment: You are not using 'lazy' correctly. We do not say 'lazy to [verb]' and it does not simply mean 'reluctant', as you seem to think. In the sense you are thinking of, it means 'Unwilling to work or use energy'. Someone might be too lazy to cook, or too lazy to study, etc. The word 'lazy' does not always have a bad meaning; it can simply mean 'unwilling to waste energy unnecessarily', as in Bill Gates' remark. The word is fine to use that way.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Based on your explanation so my brother is not lazy but what?

Comment: Friendly Ghost, your brother is not 'lazy to study', etc, he is **too lazy to study**, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The implication of Bill Gates' usage is that someone who is used to doing  as little as possible to satisfy a requirement will be the person most likely to arrive quickly at an effective solution (always assuming they are sufficiently intelligent and incentivised!).

A [***slacker***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slacker), perhaps - a person and especially a young person who is perceived to be disaffected, apathetic, cynical, or lacking ambition; a person who shirks work or obligation.  'Slacker' is also the adjectival form (*My slacker brother...etc*).

Comment: Why is *lazy* not as good as *slacker*?

Comment: @kris - impossible (and presumptuous)  to say what Bill Gates said 'better' than he said it himself.  I understood the OP to be seeking an *alternative* word to 'lazy'.

Comment: There was no reference to anyone's intended meaning; the above comment stands alone on its own.

Comment: @Kris - I don't understand your question.

Comment: The problem with slacker is that it (as pointed out in the answer) implies apathy toward doing an adequate job. The point of the OP quote is that work will get done, just with minimal effort.

Comment: @ScottM - yes, although you might say the same about a lazy person ("...apathy toward doing an adequate job").  An incentivised, intelligent slacker could be just the person for the job (i.e. they are used to doing as little as possible to satisfy a requirement  ).

Comment: @Dan - I don't usually see the terms used that way. "Lazy" generally relates to how much effort a person is willing to put forth, whereas "slacker" is more of a character trait relating to general attitude toward life. That is, a lazy person may not do an adequate job because they can't motivate themselves to put forth the effort, but a slacker wouldn't even give it a second thought.

Comment: @ScottM - I've been turning 'lazy' over in mind since posting.  I agree that 'a lazy person' can more easily be viewed positively than 'a slack person'.  A lazy afternoon is generally a good thing.  That said, both words have serious negative potential!